# How to bubble sort an array of objects(list(of class)) in visual basic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, bubble-sort

[bubble sort psudo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChciW.png)
i wish to use the psudo code above as the foundation to make the bubble sort

ive declared a public array of objects:

```
Dim Exercises As New List(Of Exercises)
```

i have a class of exercises:

```
Public Class Exercises
    'properties
    Private _Name As String
    Private _Position As String
    Private _Equipment As String
    Private _bodyPart As String
    Private _beginnerStandard As Integer
    Private _noviceStandard As Integer
    Private _intermediateStandard As Integer
    Private _advancedStandard As Integer
    Private _eliteStandard As Integer

    Public Sub New() 'default constructor
        Name = ""
        Position = ""
        Equipment = ""
        bodyPart = ""
        beginnerStandard = 0
        noviceStandard = 0
        intermediateStandard = 0
        advancedStandard = 0
        advancedStandard = 0
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Position As String, ByVal Equipment As String, ByVal bodypart As String, ByVal beginnerStandard As Integer,
                         ByVal noviceStandard As Integer, ByVal intermediateStandard As Integer, ByVal advancedStandard As Integer, ByVal eliteStandard As Integer)
        'overloaded constructor
        _Name = Name
        _Position = Position
        _Equipment = Equipment
        _bodyPart = bodypart
        _beginnerStandard = beginnerStandard
        _noviceStandard = noviceStandard
        _intermediateStandard = intermediateStandard
        _advancedStandard = advancedStandard
        _eliteStandard = eliteStandard
    End Sub
    'getters and setters for the properties
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Position As String
        Get
            Return _Position
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Position = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Equipment As String
        Get
            Return _Equipment
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Equipment = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property bodyPart As String
        Get
            Return _bodyPart
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _bodyPart = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property beginnerStandard As Integer
        Get
            Return _beginnerStandard
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _beginnerStandard = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property noviceStandard As Integer
        Get
            Return _noviceStandard
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _noviceStandard = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property intermediateStandard As Integer
        Get
            Return _intermediateStandard
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _intermediateStandard = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property advancedStandard As Integer
        Get
            Return _advancedStandard
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _advancedStandard = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property eliteStandard As Integer
        Get
            Return _eliteStandard
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _eliteStandard = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Might be better to ignore this section as it may not make sense and will likely confuse**

ive tried searching how todo it up but did not find any answers or videos.
ive given it a go below but its incomplete:

```
Sub bubbleSort(ByVal OrderAscDesc, ByVal orderColumn)
        Dim tempHolder As Exercises
        Dim outer As Integer = getArrayOfObjectsLength()
        Dim noSwap As Boolean = True

        If OrderAscDesc = "ASC" Then
            While Not (outer = -1) Or noSwap = False
                noSwap = True
                For Each obj In Exercises
                    If obj.

                    End If
            Next
            End While
        ElseIf OrderAscDesc = "DESC" Then

        End If
    End Sub
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/
    Function getArrayOfObjectsLength()
        Dim elements = 0
        For Each obj In Exercises
            elements += Exercises.Name.Length
        Next
        Dim newArray(elements - 1) As Integer
        Dim index = 0
        For Each obj In Exercises
            Dim n = Exercises.Result.Length
            Array.Copy(Exercises.Result, 0, newArray, index, n)
            index += n
        Next
        Console.WriteLine($"The new array has {newArray.Length} elements.")
    End Function
```

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest using automatic properties to make your code more concise and readable.  (i.e. remove `Private _Name As String` and remove the part from `Get` to `End Property` in the `Property Name` declaration so in the end all you have is the single line `Public Property Name As String`.)

Comment: It needs to be able to compare two instances of the "Exercises" class. You can define that behaviour yourself - you could start learning how to at [How to: Define an Operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-define-an-operator). (Also, I suspect that "Exercise" would be a better name for the class.)

Comment: Really, there isn't a question her that can be answered by anyone but yourself.  It is straight down to which property of the Exercises class you want to order your array by.  Would also suggest, bubble sorts have one of the most common homework tasks for years, so there will be literal hundreds of examples around to follow

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub bubbleSort(ByVal OrderAscDesc, ByVal orderColumn)
        Dim outer As Integer = getArrayOfObjectsLength()
        Dim noSwap As Boolean = True

        If OrderAscDesc = "ASC" Then
            While Not (outer = -1) Or noSwap = False
                noSwap = True
                For inner = 0 To outer
                    If Exercises(inner).Name > Exercises(inner + 1).Name Then
                        Dim tempholder As Exercise = Exercises(inner)
                        Exercises(inner) = Exercises(inner + 1)
                        Exercises(inner + 1) = tempholder
                    End If
                Next
            End While
        ElseIf OrderAscDesc = "DESC" Then
            While Not (outer = -1) Or noSwap = False
                noSwap = True
                For inner = 0 To outer
                    If Exercises(inner).Name < Exercises(inner + 1).Name Then
                        Dim tempholder As Exercise = Exercises(inner)
                        Exercises(inner) = Exercises(inner + 1)
                        Exercises(inner + 1) = tempholder
                    End If
                Next
            End While
        End If
    End Sub
    Function getArrayOfObjectsLength()
        'code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/
        Dim elements = 0
        For Each obj In Exercises
            elements += 1
            'elements += obj.Name.Length
        Next
        'Dim newArray(elements - 1) As Integer
        'Dim index = 0
        'For Each obj In Exercises
        '    Dim n = obj.Name.Length
        '    'Array.Copy(obj.Name, 0, newArray, index, n)
        '    index += n
        'Next
        'MsgBox("testing length of object: " & elements) 'test. expected lenght to be 21. TRUE
        'Console.WriteLine($"The new array has {newArray.Length} elements.")
        Return elements
    End Function
    Sub fetchResults(ByVal OrderAscDesc, ByVal orderColumn, ByVal searchStr, ByVal position, ByVal equipment, ByVal bodyPart)

        bubbleSort(OrderAscDesc, orderColumn)
        binarySearch()

    End Sub
    Private Sub exerciseSearchSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exerciseSearchSubmit.Click
        Dim searchStr, position, equipment, bodyPart As String
        'Dim searchBlank, posBlank, equipBlank, bpBlank As Boolean
        'Dim sqlWhereSearchCriteria As String = ""
        Dim OrderAscDesc As String 'a is asc, d is desc
        Dim orderColumn As String

        OrderAscDesc = InputBox("type a for asc or d for desc")
        OrderAscDesc = validateAscDesc(OrderAscDesc)

        orderColumn = InputBox("what column do you want to sort by? options are: 'Name', 'Position', 'Equipment', 'bodyPart'")
        orderColumn = validateColumn(orderColumn)

        searchStr = searchExerciseTextbox.ToString
        position = exercisePositionComboBox.ToString
        equipment = exerciseEquipmentComboBox.ToString
        bodyPart = bodyPartComboBox.ToString

        fetchResults(OrderAscDesc, orderColumn, searchStr, position, equipment, bodyPart)
```